# JMeter - Detecting a TransactionController Sampler in Beanshell Listener

Tags: jmeter

Is there a way to determine in a BeanShell Listener script if a Sample Result/Event is under a Transaction Controller?

I know you can use `sampleEvent.isTransactionSampleEvent()` to determine if the event is for TransactionController. But is it possible to check, in the below example, when executing the BeanShell Listener for HTTP Request 2, if it is under Transaction Controller?

```
Thread Group
  HttpRequest 1  
  TransactionController  
    HttpRequest 2  
    HttpRequest 3  
  HttpRequest 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not name your sampler with a suffix (-underTC) and test this in your listener:

- JMeterContext#getCurrentSampler()#getName()

Trying to use internal JMeter API might break you Test in the future.

Comment: Essentially my script is sending messages to Splunk on the timings and data for each Request. However, for those under TransactionController I want to send slightly different sets of data, so I need to distinguish if possible these type of elements.

I have found a workaround which involves adding a different individual Beanshell Listener to each TransactionController element but would like someway of using the same Listener for all with a method of detecting the different types of elements.